# How to login users to Wordpress programmatically?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I am logging in users without password like this. It works on the page they login, but as soon as the visit another page inside the blog, the are logged out?! What have I done wrong here?

I am aware of the other posts for this topic, but none of them shows problems like I do. Thanks for your help!

```
    if (!is_user_logged_in() ){
        $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $user_login = $user_info->user_login; 
        wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id); 
        do_action('wp_login', $user_login);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to log them in automatically without a password? It just seem like an open invitation to allow bots hijack your site.

Comment: I have built my own https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless/guides/email-magic-link kind of script. And it works unless the loggedin user changes a page.